# Understanding components and vector derivative in general curvilinear coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I'm studying introductory vector calculus and need to confirm/clarify my concepts. The definition of the derivative of a vector (for example in $\mathbb{R}^2$) **if the unit vectors are constant throughout the 2D space** is in terms of its components: if we have $r(t)=(x(t), y(t))$ **in the standard Cartesian basis**, then

$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}e_x+\frac{dy}{dt}e_y$$

Now if we move to polar coordinates $\rho, \phi$, then the unit basis vectors $e_{\rho},e_{\phi}$ will change direction depending on the location in 2D space. To define the derivative in this case, the book that I'm studying gives the following quick method: we see that $r=\rho e_{\rho}$ (where $\rho$ is the distance of the vector's endpoint from the origin), which means
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{d\rho}{dt}e_{\rho}+\rho\frac{de_{\rho}}{dt}$$
[image]

So far, so good: $\frac{d\rho}{dt}$ can be calculated since we can express $\rho$ in terms of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, and differentiate that expression w.r.t. $t$. In this specific case, we can also express $e_{\rho}=(\cos\phi)e_x + (\sin\phi)e_y$. **It turns out that** $$\frac{de_{\rho}}{dt}=\frac{d\phi}{dt}e_{\phi}$$ **because of the specific way $e_{\rho}$ and $e_{\phi}$ are defined in terms of $e_x$ and $e_y$**.

Expressing the same vector $r$ in a general curvilinear coordinate system $u,v$,
[image]

To even start differentiating $r$, we need to find the components of $r$ in the new system. I'm **assuming** the way to identify $r$ is to identify it as the intersection of two coordinate curves $u=c_1$ and $v=c_2$ - in this case, $u=5$ and $v=4$. **Is my understanding correct? Is this the way to identify the components of a vector in a curvilinear system?**

So if we have some differentiable functions $f,g$ such that $u=f(x,y)$ and $v=g(x,y)$ and $r=ue_u+ve_v$, then
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{du}{dt}e_u+u\frac{de_u}{dt}+\frac{dv}{dt}e_v+v\frac{de_v}{dt}$$

$\frac{du}{dt}$ can be identified as $\frac{df(x(t),y(t))}{dt}$ and can be evaluated. **How does one, in general, express basis vectors $e_u$ and $e_v$ in terms of $e_x$ and $e_y$?** And even if we do manage to define curvilinear basis vectors in terms of $e_x,e_y$, **it's not necessary that we'll get a nice expression for $\frac{de_u}{dt}$ and $\frac{de_v}{dt}$ in terms of $e_u$ and $e_v$. How do we get the curvilinear components of $\frac{dr}{dt}$ in that case?**

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/521493/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "differentiation" in curvilinear coordinates. But you can set all this up with parameterizations. If you want to describe a point in $\mathbb R^2$, "the target", you can do it by using the natural coordinates, mapping them via functions from $\mathbb R^2$, "the source". That is, define

$\phi:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ by $\phi(x,y)=(\phi_1(x,y),\phi_2(x,y)).$

For example, if we take $\phi_1(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\phi_2(x,y)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$, we get polar coordinates. Of course, we have to be careful: if $x=0$, this parameterization won't work, but  if we use another branch of arctan, we will get a different parameterization, one that works.

As another example, take $\phi(x,y)=(x,y),$ the identity. This will give us the usual coordinates on $\mathbb R^2.$

Notice that in the second example, there is no problem if we move the points around; the same $\phi$ will work for all of them. Whereas, in the first case, there may be some "bad points", for which $\phi$ won't work.

Now let $(u,v):=(\phi_1(x,y),\phi_2(x,y))$ for conveience, and notice that if we fix a point $(u_0,v_0)$, and if we move out from $(u_0,v_0)$ to some nearby $(u,v)$, the points will generally traverse a complicated path. So it makes sense to affix a $\textit{whole coordinate system at}\ (u_0,v_0)$, and then as the point moves, we will get coordinate systems that move along with it as we go from $(u_0,v_0)$ to $(u,v)$ along the path specified by $\phi.$ You can visualize this process by thinking of pasting tangents at each point on the curvy lines you drew above. These are the (local) coordinate systems.

Notice also that if $\phi(x,y)=(x,y)$, the identity, the coordinate systems all look the same as we go from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x,y)$. At some intermediate point $(x_1,y_1)$ the $x$ component "points in the $x$ direction" and the $y$ component "points in the $y$ direction".

But when $\phi$ is more complicated, we see that the tangents are changing as we move along, so we need to know how to calculate them, because it is the tangents that will give us our (local) coordinate systems.  But this is easy! We already know how to find tangents for vector-valued functions that map open subsets of $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R^2.$

More precisely, if we fix $v_0$ and let $u_0$ move to a nearby value $u_0+\Delta u$, we get a $\textit{curve},\ \vec r$ in $\mathbb R^2, $ as  $(u,v_0)$ traces out a path in $\mathbb R^2$ and its tangent at $(u_0,v_0)$ is $\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial u}$, evaluated at $(u_0,v_0).$ Now, define $\vec e_1:=\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial u}/\left|\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial u}\right|$, where the denominator is just the scaling factor that normalizes $\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial u}$.

Similarly, we define $\vec e_2:=\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial v}/\left|\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial v}\right|.$

Now that we have the machinery in place, we can do an example:

$u=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}:=r$ and $v=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$. Of course, we usually write $u=r$ and $v=\theta.$ Then, $\vec r(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ and so

$\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial r}=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial \theta}=(-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta).$ Therefore,

$\vec e_1=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)/1=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $\vec e_2=\frac{1}{r}(-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta).$

Now that we have the basis vectors (in the tangent space), as functions of $r$ and $\theta$, we can differentiate them in the usual way.

If you repeat this calculation for $\phi(x,y)=(x,y)$, you will get $\vec e_1=(1,0)$ and $\vec e_2=(0,1)$, and obtain the familiar result that, in standard coordinates, the tangent spaces at each point in $\mathbb R^2$ all point in the same direction, which is why we get away with treating them as constants when we differentiate vectors, expressed in that coordinate system.

edit: you mentioned covariant and contravariant components in the comments. This picture may help to see what is going on

[image]

The point $p=(u_0,v_0)$ is fixed in the lower left-hand corner. $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the tangent vectors to the curves $\vec r(u,v_0)$ and $\vec r(u_0,v)$ at $p$.

The covariant components are the orthogonal projections onto the coordinate axes defined by $e_1$ and $e_2$ while the contravariant components are the coordinates of $M$ in the $\{e_1,e_2\}$ basis at $p$.

Everything is going on at $p$. If we change it, then presumably, the $x_i,\ x^i$ and $e_i$ change as well. And the calculation we did above tells us exactly how they change as $p$ changes.

Comment: Perfect answer! One thing then that I'd still like to confirm: from what you said, the basis vectors in curvilinear coordinate systems are defined locally, so it makes sense to express the **vector differential** $d\mathbf{r}$ in terms of the **local** basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_u,\mathbf{e}_v$. By "local" I mean the vectors defined in the tangent space of the origin point of $d\mathbf{r}$ [cont'd]...

Comment: [cont'd]... Does that mean it's not possible to express the non-differential vector $\mathbf{r}$ (as you see in the 2nd figure of the question) in terms of basis vectors in curvilinear coordinates? i.e. Does that mean the expression  $\mathbf{r}=u\mathbf{e}_u+v\mathbf{e}_v$ makes no sense?

Comment: $\bf r$ is OK. It's a function that maps from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$, if I am reading it correctly. The point is that in curvilinear coordinates, we use the $tangents$ to measure what happens as the point moves along. This amounts to placing coordinate systems defined by the partial derivatives, at each point and seeing how they "move" as we move the point. I look at it like changing the camera angle as the point moves along. This does not happen in standard coordinates because the "camera angle" does not change. Mathematically: the position and tangent vectors are the same.

Comment: I see, but what I meant was: suppose you just have a vector in curvilinear coordinates (ref. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHM0D.png ). I can express this nicely in canonical coordinates as, say $\mathbf{a}=a_x\hat i + a_y\hat j$. What I'm struggling with is making the transition to curvilinear. **How** can we write $\mathbf{a}$ in this same form for curvilinear? Can we even write $\mathbf{a} = a_u\mathbf{e}_u+a_v\mathbf{e}_v$ for some $a_u$ and $a_v$? And if so, what's the "recipe" for finding their values? Your answer gives me the big picture, but could I have concrete details?

Comment: Yes. In a nbhd of $(u_0,v_0)$ you have $\vec r(u,v)=a(u,v)\vec e_1(u,v)+b(u,v)\vec e_2(u,v)$. I do not use the subscripts $u$ and $v$ so as not to confuse them with partial derivatives. What's going on here is that $\phi$ is locally invertible, so you use the inverse function theorem on it. Think of two copies of $\mathbb R^2$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi$ that maps a small open set $(x_0,x_1)\in U\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ to a small open set $(u_0,v_0)\in V\subseteq \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: But this representation of $\mathbf{a}$, i.e., $\mathbf{a}=a(u,v)\mathbf{e}_1(u,v)+b(u,v)\mathbf{e}_2(u,v)$ is only local to the neighborhood, right? As in this representation holds **only** in this neighborhood? If we shift to some other neighborhood, then the representation will change? And that means there's no **global** representation of $\mathbf{a}$ in terms of curvilinear basis? Sorry for the many questions and if I sound dense - I'm new to the subject and want to be absolutely clear on concepts.

Comment: You questions are great. This stuff is confusing! And yes, in theory, the charts are local. But in cases like polar coordinates, you don't really notice it because polar coordinates are defined for any simply connected subset that does not contain the origin. .  I never really understood this material until I started self.studying differential geometry. A book that helped me a lot was [Loring Tu's Intro to Manifolds](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441973993).

Comment: Thanks! I'll refer to that book for sure and give 50 of my bounty to the answer because you've been so helpful. One last bit that I want to confirm: We're not calculating the components w.r.t. a global coordinate system, but instead the components depend on which point we choose for the tangent space. e.g. if you consider this figure: imgur.com/LivdZlQ , then if we want to find the coordinates of $P$, we first have to decide w.r.t. which point's tangent space. Suppose we choose $Q$, then find the coordinate curves passing through it, ... [cont'd in next comment]

Comment: [cont'd]... then define unit vectors tangent to the curves at $Q$ to form a linear coordinate system, and then determine the covariant $u$ component to be $QB$. If we'd selected $R$, then we'd repeat the same thing - define a linear coordinate system in the tangent space at $R$ and do a perpendicular projection to find the covariant component as $RA$. So the values of co- and contravariant components will depend on whether we'd chosen $Q$ or $R$ or any other point, and there's no such thing as "global" components. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Maybe we mixing up two different things here.The coordinate grid is the family of lines along which only one of $u$ or $v$ varies.  The position of any point is given by $\vec r(u,v)$, which is just an ordered pair in $\mathbb R^2.$ So, the points $Q$ and $R$ will have different $\vec r$ values. We were discussing something else in this thread, though; namely, how the tangent vectors at each point behave as the point moves. We do not notice any difference with the usual coordinates because although the points change, the tangent vectors do not. Cont. below

Comment: On the other hand, if the coordinates are curvilinear, then the base tangent vectors $do$ change, and we calculated how they change above. (We need to know this because if the tangent vectors change, then so will their gradients, curls, etc.) At each point we find a basis of these tangent vectors, called the covariant basis because these vectors are always tangent to the grid lines and they stretch or shrink in proportion to how much the grid lines stretch or shrink. Cont. below

Comment: The bottom line is that the full description of this situation is that we are working with tuples $(p,v)$, where $p\in \mathbb R^2$ and $v$ is a vector written in the basis of the tangent space at $p$. Now, the contravariant basis forms another two dimensional vector space at $p$, but it is derived in a different way. I can post an image if you want.

Comment: I posted a pic appended to my answer. Not to beat a dead horse, but there is a very nice exposition of this [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-662-43444-4%2F1.pdf). And if you have some background in algebra and topology,  the sections "tangent bundle" and "cotangent bundle" in the book I linked will be of great help. At least, they really brought all these ideas together for me.

Comment: Well, full disclosure: my previous comment was in reference to this closely related question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/521262/covariant-and-contravariant-components-of-a-vector-in-curvilinear-coordinate-sys. Since you seem comfortable in the subject, I thought I'd clarify my understanding of that question from one of its answers. Also, thank you for the additional reference - seems very useful! I'll keep it handy as I study more about tensors